# Undefined variable when converting a ternary operator into traditional if statement

Tags: javascript, variables, backbone.js, eslint, ternary

I'm using eslint to fix some coding standards in my backbone app. I have the following function in a view (simplified code):

```
getData: function(foo){
   var self = this;
   $.when(foo).then(function(){
      var doUpdate = false;

      self.makeAjaxRequest().done(function(data){
         self.trigger(doUpdate === false ? "foo" : "bar");
      });
   }
}
```

I'm needing to convert the ternary operator to a standard if statement. So I tried this:

```
getData: function(foo){
   var self = this;
   $.when(foo).then(function(){
      var doUpdate = false;

      self.makeAjaxRequest().done(function(data){
         self.trigger(function(){
            if(doUpdate === false) {
               return "foo";
            }

            return "bar";
         });
      });
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems to cause issues in the code. I wonder if I'm referencing doUpdate correctly. Where have I gone wrong in this conversion?

Comment: your argument to self.trigger  is a function ... you need to add `()` after the closing `}` of the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the original code, `trigger` is called with the value `"foo"` or `"bar"`.

In your updated code, `trigger` is called *with a function*.

You never called the function you replaced the conditional with.

I would keep the conditional version, but if you want to use your alternative instead, *call* your function:

```
getData: function(foo){
   var self = this;
   $.when(foo).then(function(){
      var doUpdate = false;

      self.makeAjaxRequest().done(function(data){
         self.trigger(function(){
            if(doUpdate === false) {
               return "foo";
            }

            return "bar";
         }());
//        ^^--------------- Note
      });
   }
}
```

If you need to remove the conditional, though, I wouldn't do it that way. Instead:

```
getData: function(foo){
   var self = this;
   $.when(foo).then(function(){
      var doUpdate = false;

      self.makeAjaxRequest().done(function(data){
         var triggerWith;
         if (doUpdate === false) {
            triggerWith = "foo";
         } else {
            triggerWith = "bar";
         }
         self.trigger(triggerWith);
      });
   }
}
```

---

Side note: Unless you have a real need to *specifically* check for `false` and not the various other falsy values, which doesn't appear to be the case in that code, just `if (!doUpdate)` rather than `if (doUpdate === false)` is the usual way.

Comment: I've ended up using Nina Scholz's answer in this case. However, the is a correct answer which fixed other issues I had

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the if clause directly before calling `self.trigger`?

```
self.makeAjaxRequest().done(function(data) {
    if (doUpdate) {
        self.trigger("bar");
    } else {
        self.trigger("foo");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty on my Backbone, but afaik it isn't possible to use `[Backbone.Events.trigger](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-46) with a function as an argument. You *could* however turn it in to an iife (or make it a named function).

```
self.trigger((function(){
    if(doUpdate === false) {
        return "foo";
    }

    return "bar";
}()));
```

or as a named function

```
function getUpdateEventName(doUpdate) {
    if(doUpdate === false) {
        return "foo";
    }

    return "bar";
}

self.trigger(getUpdateEventName(doUpdate));
```